# How do I add a second domain in Exchange 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I have the following virtual machine running:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2
- Microsoft Exchange 2010 SP1

I must admit that I am new with Windows Server and Exchange. I have however worked with Exchange 2003 and Windows Server 2003 and was successfully able to add domains and mailboxes, although I just used the active directory to add domains and to add users with an e-mail box.

I have added the 2nd domain via the Exchange Management Console under "Accepted Domains" (Organisation -> Hub Transport). The domain however did not appear in the dropdown box when I clicked new mailbox, it only listed the original server hostname domain.

On the internet I searched for about an hour for more information, but I have still not been able to find out how I can use the added domain for a new mailbox. I saw some information about "new email address policy", but when I looked at the [instructions](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1240-how-to-create-and-manage-exchange-server-2010-e-mail-address-policies/) and the wizard, there was not much that made me think it would allow me to use the domain afterwards, especially since I could not select the new domain as recipient container.

I have added a new authoritative accepted domain for the organisation an new mail address policy.

```
New-AcceptedDomain -Name "mydomain.info” -DomainName mydomain.info -DomainType Authoritative
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name “@mydomain.info” -IncludedRecipients UserMailbox ConditionalDepartment “Fourth Coffee” -Priority 1 -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates “SMTP:@fourthcoffee.com”
Update-EmailAddressPolicy -Identity “@mydomain.info”
```

When I click "New mailbox" still only the local domain name is listed.

Comment: You will need to apply this address policy to your users. Do this using Set-EmailAddressPolicy, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124517.aspx. It needs to be applied to an OU, and you can set other filters as well so that, for example, only people in a certain department get this new SMTP domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new authoritative accepted domain for the organisation, not just the hub transport server. You also need to create a new address policy for your mailboxes.

I also moved from Ex2k3 to 2k10, skipping 2k7, and I understand that it's a bit of a paradigm shift. That said once I got my head around the new Powershell way of doing stuff, I find it much easier, especially seeing as how slow the Exchange console is by comparison. But that's an aside. The point is you can do this using either method and the Microsoft documentation will show you both ways. I'd recommend putting in the effort and learning to do it via the shell.

For your specific problem look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124911.aspx), [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125137.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997443.aspx).